# How to sort xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a simple xml file as follows;

```
'<Clubs>
  <Club>Long Sutton Golf Club</Club>
  <Club>Enmore Park</Club>
  <Club>Wheathill</Club>
  <Club>Axe Cliff</Club>
  <Club>Taunton &amp; Pickeridge</Club>
  <Club>Oake Manor GC</Club>
  <Club>Westbury GC</Club>
  <Club>Cumberwell Park</Club>
  <Club>Minehead &amp; W Somerset GC</Club>
  <Club>Burnham &amp; Berrow GC</Club>
  <Club>Bath GC</Club>
  <Club>Wells GC</Club>
  <Club>Mendip GC</Club>
  <Club>Mendip Spring GC</Club>
</Clubs>'
```

I want to sort the clubs into alphabetical order so I have used a xslt file

This is the xsl code

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Clubs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Club">
        <xsl:sort select="Club" data-type="text"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>'
```

this is my VB.net code invoking the xsl file

```
'Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
 xslt.Load(Path & "\Clubs.xsl")

 ' Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
 xslt.Transform(Path & "\Clubs.xml", Path & "\sortedClubs.xml")'
```

I expected the sortClubs.xml to have the clubs sorted but it just copies the Clubs.xml without sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your apply-templates you select `Club`. In your sort you also select `Club` which would sort based on a child `Club` (which doesn’t exist).

Try selecting `.` (current node) in your sort instead...

```
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="text"/>
```

Comment: Note also that both `select="."` and `data-type="text"` are the default values, so you could just write `<xsl:sort/>`.

Comment: Daniel thanks for the solution, works perfectly. I have gone with Micheal solution as it uses a later version of xls stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in XSLT 3.0 the entire stylesheet reduces to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <Clubs><xsl:copy-of select="sort(/*/Club)"/></Clubs>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Micheal Thanks for the solution it works perfectly. Cannot seem to get my mind around xsl stylesheets.

Comment: Micheal when I ran the code a second time I got this error System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: ''sort()' is an unknown XSLT function.' against the line 'xslt.Transform(Path & "\Clubs.xml", Path & "\sortedClubs.xml")'.   Reverted to Daniel solution

Comment: @DaveTheGolfer, to use XSLT 3 you need to use an XSLT 3 processor, for the .NET framework you can use Saxon 9.8 or later HE, available on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/ or SourceForge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/. Not sure what you used the first time but Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform are XSLT 1 processors and certainly never supported the XPath 3 `sort` function used in Michael's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  I will stick with version 1